# Put method in asp.net mvc REST service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, api

I put data to my api using the code below:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear(); 
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsJsonAsync($"/api/Home/UpdateEmpDetails/{id}", newEmployee).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

but I get the following error:

```
{StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin Connection: close Date: Thu, 05 Oct 2017 05:26:07 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Content-Length: 1293 Allow: GET Allow: HEAD Allow: OPTIONS Allow: TRACE Content-Type: text/html }}
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

WebDAV module may cause 405 error, so make sure you have WebDAV module not installed. Check if it is installed from Control Panel > "Turn Windows Features On or Off". If you don’t need to use WebDAV then remove "WebDAV Publishing" to fix "405 method not allowed" issue.

Or you may it fix it for only this project by adding the following to web.config of your WebApi project:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule"/> <!-- add to remove webdav -->
</modules>
```

Comment: I removed  "WebDAV Publishing", but the problem is still remaining.